# How to create Simple Web Server with Mbed and W5100 Ethernet Shield

Tags: arduino, arm, ethernet, mbed, website

I'm trying to develop a simple web server application with Nucleo f411re and w5100 Ethernet shield. My question is why the client.is_fin_received() function always returns 0. Why doesn't my web page complete?

PS : I have no idea about http protocol and html. I think the CR and LF ( '\n' '\r') characters are wrong.

Here is my main.cpp file

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "WIZnetInterface.h"

#define USE_W5100
#define ST_NUCLEO
#define MYPORT    80

const char * IP_Addr    = "192.168.2.141";
const char * IP_Subnet  = "255.255.255.0";
const char * IP_Gateway = "192.168.1.1";
unsigned char MAC_Addr[6] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};

Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);

SPI spi(PA_7,PA_6,PA_5);
WIZnetInterface ethernet(&spi,PB_6,PA_10);

char page[]={"\r\nHTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html><body><h1>PAGE</h1></body></html>\r\n\r\n"};

int i=0;

int main() {

pc.baud(9600);
pc.printf("Start\r\n");
char buffer[300];

while(1)
{
int ret = ethernet.init(MAC_Addr,IP_Addr,IP_Subnet,IP_Gateway);

if (!ret) {
    pc.printf("Initialized, MAC: %s\r\n", ethernet.getMACAddress());
    ret = ethernet.connect();
    if (!ret) {
        pc.printf("IP: %s, MASK: %s, GW: %s\r\n",
                  ethernet.getIPAddress(), ethernet.getNetworkMask(), ethernet.getGateway());
    } else {
        pc.printf("Error ethernet.connect() - ret = %d\r\n", ret);
        exit(0);
    }
} else {
    pc.printf("Error ethernet.init() - ret = %d\r\n", ret);
    exit(0);
}

TCPSocketServer server;
server.bind(MYPORT);
server.listen();

while (1) {
    pc.printf("\nWait for new connection...\r\n");
    TCPSocketConnection client;
    server.accept(client);
    client.set_blocking(false, 0); // Timeout=0.
    pc.printf("Connection from: %s\r\n", client.get_address());
    while (client.is_connected() == true) {
        int n = client.receive(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        client.send(page,sizeof(page));

        wait(1);

        n = client.receive(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        for(i=0; i<sizeof(buffer); i++)
        {
            pc.printf("%c",buffer[i]);
            if(buffer[i]==' ')
                pc.printf("\r\n");
        }

        pc.printf("\nclient is fin received : %d\r\n",client.is_fin_received());
        if(client.is_fin_received())
            client.close();
    }
    pc.printf("Disconnected.\r\n");
    }
}
}
```

Result:
[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that platform but two possibilities I can see are:

- I don't think you need the extra CR/LF at the start of your response (but probably not the main issue).
- You're not including `Content-Length` in the header so I think the client will be waiting for the socket to be closed at your end which is why `is_fin_received()` never returns true.

So I'd try including the `Content-Length` header which is the length of the of the main body. I'm fairly sure it needs to be the length including the CR/LF characters but you should get an HTTP error response if it's wrong and can adjust.

Comment: I edited page[] array as **char page[]={"\r\nHTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nContent-Length: 39\r\n\r\n<html><body><h1>PAGE</h1></body></html>\r\n\r\n"};** and problem solved .I really appreciate your help thank you so much.